# How to compare date and year?

Tags: android

i am implementing one graph related app.

In that when application start i am getting present month,present year from calende and display on the screen with graph. like April 2012 and graph

ok that is fine.

In my screen i have two buttons like preview,next.

when user clicks preview ,i want to change April 2012 to March 2012,Fib 2012 ..........

And when user clicks next button,i want to change April 2012 to May 2012.....

How i will do these type of comparigens.

If any one know please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use dat.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); and see this example [android-calendar-view](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/source/browse/trunk/src/com/exina/android/calendar/TestActivity.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Calendar Instance to set time.. When user presses next increment month by one and set it to Calendar and get Date from it.. and The opposite for previous..  But using default `DatePicker` is a lot better Option..

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use the [`add(int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method on a Calendar instance.

```
mCalendar.add(Calendar.Month, 1) // next month
mCalendar.add(Calendar.Month, -1) // previous month
```

Comment: hi if u don't mind please give some sample code,thanks for u'r reply

Comment: but this code only subtract and add  1 day from the current month

Comment: Please read again: the code is adding months, not days, which is exactly what was being asked. Anyways, obviously you can fill in any value for the (-)`1`. Also, since the the underlying calendar object will change after the addition, you can iteratively go to any month you like... You are correct if you were trying to say you can use the same method for adding days, but the same is true for years etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int cmonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int cyear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
//when you click next in click event call this below three lines
mCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1); // next month
cmonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
cyear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

//when you click previous in click event call this below tthree lines
mCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // previous month
cmonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
cyear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```